# Can I play Demon's Souls over LAN?

Tags: demons-souls

It appears [Demon's Souls online will be turning off soon](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2012/04/11/demon-39-s-souls-going-offline-end-of-may.aspx).

I have 2 PS3s; after the servers go offline will I be able to play the game with a friend over LAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not.

Online Play in Demon's Souls requires the server to function. It will not work over LAN.

Comment: http://www.co-optimus.com/game/1370/Playstation_3/Demons_Souls.html